# Number of nonnegative integral solutions of $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +\cdots + x_m = k $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

What I'm tyring to show is the number of solutions to the equation of natural numbers;

$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +\cdots + x_m = k
$$
is equal to 
$$ \binom{m + k - 1} m
$$

To be blunt, I have no idea where to start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a string with $k$ symbols, which you need to partitition into $m$ regions, say by inserting $m-1$ separator characters `"|"`. That gives your total string of length $k+m-1$, of which you need to pick where the $m-1$ separators go.

the total number of ways to do that is $k+m-1\choose{m-1}$

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. it always amazes me how i can miss things like this