# Number of ways to write N as a sum of K non-negative integers

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know if there is a generic way to write a number *N* as a sum of *K* integers. The integer can be 0, 1, 2...*N*. For example, 3 expressed as a sum of 2 numbers can be {0,3} {3,0} {1,2} {2,1} , thank you.

Comment: Look up stars and bars combinatorics,

Comment: The general answer, when counting different permutations as you do, is $(N+1)^{k-1}$. From the "stars and bars" idea, you have to place $k-1$ bars, and you can place them between any of the $N$ stars, as well as at the ends.

Comment: See [Number of nonnegative integral solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_m = k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219666/number-of-nonnegative-integral-solutions-of-x-1-x-2-x-3-cdots-x-m-k?rq=1).